# Excel VBA splitting a string into a rectanglar of cells

Tags: excel, vba

My program has two input boxes. It first get a string and then get a rectangular dimension and split the string characters into cells of rectangular.
For example:
The string input may be: "U.S. government plans to cull 11000 Oregon birds to save salmon" 
The dimension of rectangular may be: 6*9
The result should be:

```
  A B C D E F G H I J 
1 u . s . g o v e r n 
2 m e n t p l a n s t 
3 o c u l l 1 1 0 0 0
4 o r e g o n b i r d 
5 s t o s a v e s a l 
6 m o n
```

I will be grateful if you can solve this problem.

Comment: Your inputs are the string and the dimensions?

Comment: Yes. My inputs are the string and the dimensions of the rectangular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are...:

```
Sub Solution()

    Dim intVer As Integer
    Dim intHor As Integer

    intVer = 6
    intHor = 10

    Dim strTxt As String
    strTxt = "U.S. government plans to cull 11000 Oregon birds to save salmon"
    'remove spaces
    strTxt = Replace(strTxt, " ", "")

    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    For Each Cell In Range("A1").Resize(intVer, intHor)
        i = i + 1
        Cell = Mid(strTxt, i, 1)
    Next

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go. `Dim1` and `Dim2` are your dimensions.

```
Sub Test()
Dim Str As String
Dim Dim1 As Integer: Dim1 = 9
Dim Dim2 As Integer: Dim2 = 6
Dim Counter As Integer: Counter = 1
Str = "U.S. government plans to cull 11000 Oregon birds to save salmon"
Str = Replace(Str, " ", "")
For Each cell In Range("a1", Converttoletter(Dim1) & Dim2).Cells
cell.Value = Mid(Str, Counter, 1)
Counter = Counter + 1
Next
End Sub

Function ConvertToLetter(I As Integer) As String
Converttoletter = Chr(96 + I)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub MAIN()
    Dim s As String, r As Range
    s = "Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country."
    Set r = Range("A1:G30")
    Call Fracture(s, r)
End Sub


Sub Fracture(st As String, rng As Range)
    Dim r As Range
    Dim L As Long, i As Long
    L = Len(st)
    i = 1
    For Each r In rng
        r.Value = Mid(st, i, 1)
        i = i + 1
        If i > L Then Exit Sub
    Next r
End Sub
```